# Perfectly Fine Working Eclipse Project throws 404 on Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, tomcat, joinfaces

I have a web application which includes `Spring Boot , Joinfaces , JSF and Spring Security`. This web application works excellent when i run in ECLIPSE IDE. All pages works fine with 0 Error.

The thing is when i do mvn install and package this project into WAR and deploy it in TOMCAT its just not working. No deploy error. Just `404` when i try to reach my pages.

What can cause this ? Why it is working perfectly fine on Eclipse but not working on Tomcat after packaging ?

Where should i look to solve this ?

Comment: Did you add your context path between host and your endpoint path? When deploying inside tomcat, all your endpoints will be avalaible under your application context. The default application context is the name of your war file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.

The thing is rest of the project was built to be run on embedded Tomcat as JAR. So the packaging was the problem. I ran the application as java -jar on tje distant machine and it worked.